# Content search picture web part unavailable

Tags: web-part, content-search-web-part

I want to create a Rotating Banner in SharePoint 2013 with content search web part. When I create the picture library url in this web part. The "RelevantResults" displayed "0" in the right side as below shown.

[image]

and there is also no items to show after save it.

[image]

Any body has any idea?

Comment: To have your data in search you must have crawled data first.

Comment: What kind of crawled data? Is there any specified requirements? I've uploaded several pictures in the picture library which I typed in "URL" blank.

Comment: I think I find the key point. Thanks #love thakker